# Class MarkdownModule is not an Angular module

Tags: angular, markdown

I'm using Ngx Markdown in my project and it's working but I'm still getting this error:

```
Class MarkdownModule is not an Angular module
```

Please guide if anyone got a similar error

Comment: Can you show us some code (e.g. where the error is thrown)?

Comment: `...
import { MarkdownModule } from 'ngx-markdown';



@NgModule({
   ...
  imports: [
    ...
    MarkdownModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
  ],
})
export class CardModalModule { }`